# Xcode 9 Storyboard Error while giving constraints

Tags: ios, constraints, uistoryboard, xcode9

[image: Storyboard]

The view has extended its area outside the boundary of SuperView while I provided constraints sticking to superview boundary. When I build the app, the constraint is good in device i.e. the view is as expected within the boundaries of parent view. And When I remove stack view which is inside the view, the view is perfectly placed.
This was the issue I have been facing with Xcode 8 also, particularly when working with stack-view. How to solve this issue?

There is a multiline label in the stack-view, it seems the issue is with that label. Because, when I make it single line, the view is places as per I desire. But, what's the issue with that and how can I solve it?